# CSV-import error: "Content of uploaded file was changed, please re-upload the file"

Tags: magento2, csv, import-products

Has anyone had this problem?
If I try to import a .csv file, it instantly says "Content of uploaded file was changed, please re-upload the file"

Answer (score 0):

In realation to the file in "*/vendor/magento/module-import-export/view/adminhtml/templates/import/form/before.phtml*" you shall check if file content format text in "UFT-8", or check if content is corrupted or wrong

```
    if (fileUploader.files.length > 0) {
            var file = fileUploader.files[0],
                ifrElName = this.ifrElemName,
                reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");

            reader.onerror = function () {
                jQuery('body').loader('hide');
                alert({
                    content: '{$uploaderErrorMessage}'
                });
                fileUploader.value = null;
                jQuery('iframe#' + ifrElName).remove();
                return;
            }

            if (file.lastModified !== this.loadedFileLastModified) {
                alert({
                    content: '{$uploaderErrorMessage}'
                });
                fileUploader.value = null;
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems it has something to do with the POS system that is installed, because if I disable it, the import works fine. I am waiting for the POS developer to check what the problem is.

Comment: Check if you POS system work with UFT-8 or you can set it in configuration